# Search in multiple indexes in elastica

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I am looking for a way to search in more than one index at the same time using Elastica.

I have an index `products`, and an index `user`.

`products` contains `{product_id, product_name, price}` and `user` contains `{product_id, user_name, date}`. Knowing that the `product_id` in both of them is the same, in `products` each `products_id` is unique but in `user` they're not as a user can buy the same product multiple times.

Anyway, I want to automatically get the price of a product from the `products` index while searching through the `user` index.

I know that we can search over multiple indexes like so (correct me if I'm wrong) :

```
$search = new \Elastica\Search($client);
$search->addIndex('users')
        ->addType('user')
        ->addIndex('products')
        ->addType('product');
```

But the problem is, when I write an aggregation on the `products_id` for example and then create a new query with some filters :

```
$products_agg = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Terms('products_id');
$products_agg->setField('products_id')->setSize(0);

$query = new \Elastica\Query();
$query->addAggregation($products_agg);
$query->setQuery($bool);

$search->setQuery($query);
```

How does elastica know in which index to search? How can I link this `products_id` to the other index?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to join two indexes based on a common field as in sql.

What you can do is model you data in the same index using **join datatype**

**https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/parent-join.html**

Index all documents in the same index ,

- Make all product documents - parent.
- Make all user documents as child

And the use parent-child aggregations and queries

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/parent-join.html#_parent_join_queries_and_aggregations

NOTE: ***make sure of the performance implication of parent-child mapping***
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/parent-join.html#_parent_join_and_performance

**One more thing you can do is** put all the information of the product with every user that buys it.

But this can unnecessarily waste you space and is not a good practice as per data  rules are concerned.

But since this is a search engine and elasticsearch suggests that best is to normalise and duplicate data rather that using parent-child.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) I think tho that there might be a simpler way to do this.. I'm also not sure that that datatype exists in my version of elastica.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: I'm using version `1.6.2`

Comment: In your case it is parent-child mapping with data of two types in same index in different types . Or else you can choose to duplicate the data

Answer (score 1):

The Elastica library has support for Multi Search API, The [multi search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-multi-search.html) allows to execute several search requests within the same API. The endpoint for it is `_msearch`.

The format of the requests is similar to the bulk API, The first line 
 is header part that includes which index / indices to search on, The second line includes the typical search body requests.

```
{"index" : "products", "type": "products"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10} // write your own query to get price
{"index" : "uesrs", "type" : "user"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}} // query for user
```

Check test case in [Multi/SearchTest.php](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/302b9da/test/Elastica/Multi/SearchTest.php#L129) to see how to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:
1- naming indexes with specific name like the following

```
myFirstIndex-myProjectName
mySecIndex-myProjectName
myThirdIndex-myProjectName
```

and so on.

2- that's give me the ability using * in the field of indexes to search because it accepts wildcard so i can search across multiple fields like this using kibana Dev Tools

```
GET *-myProjectName/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [ "*" ]
  },
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
}
```

this will search on each index includes -myProjectName.

Comment: I'm looking for an Elastica answer, but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query two indices with different mappings. Best way to solve your problem is to just do two queries (application-side joins). First query you do the aggregations on the user and the second you get the prices.

Another option would be to add the price to the user index. Sometimes you have to sacrifice a little space for better usability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `You can't query two indices with different mappings` source please?

Comment: Also what I am asking is possible in Elasticsearch for sure (`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 'elasticsearchServer.com/products,user/_search' --data '{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'`), so my question is how to do it using Elastica.

Comment: Yes you right, maybe my answer isn't very clear. What I understood from your question is that you are trying to do joins between the indicies, which is better done by adding the products fields inside the orders, thus sacrificing space.